# Error in multirow for HTML

Tags: multirow, html

I am using multirow in my table and getting error "Missing number, treated as zero" while generating HTML output, PDF is generated properly. What could be the issue?Here is my sample code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
Header 1 & Header 2 & Header 3 \\
\multirow{2}{*}{Test} & stuff & stuff \\
& Body 2 & Body 3
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How are you trying to generate HTML output?

Comment: Yes I am trying to generate HTML output.

Answer (score 3):

Package `multirow` was recently updated and definition of the macro patched by `tex4ht` has been changed. I will post a fix to `tex4ht`, but it will take few days before the update will be available in TeX distributions. Meanwhile, you can create file `multirow.4ht` in directory with your TeX file, with the following contents:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% multirow.4ht                         2009-05-21-09:32 %
% Copyright (C) 2004--2009      Eitan M. Gurari         %
%                                                        %
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the %
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either %
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any   %
% later version. The latest version of this license is   %
% in                                                     %
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt                %
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions %
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.                  %
%                                                        %
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".%
%                                                        %
% This Current Maintainer of this work                   %
% is Eitan M. Gurari.                                    %
%                                                        %
% If you modify this program your changing its signature %
% with a directive of the following form will be         %
% appreciated.                                           %
%            \message{signature}                         %
%                                                        %
%                             gurari@cse.ohio-state.edu  %
%                 http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari  %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\immediate\write-1{version 2009-05-21-09:32}

\def\@xmultirow[#1]#2[#3]#4[#5]#6{%
  \expandafter\multirow@piii#3\relax\end%
  \multirow@dima=#2\ht\@arstrutbox
  \advance\multirow@dima#2\dp\@arstrutbox
  \ifdim#2pt<\z@\multirow@dima=-\multirow@dima\fi
  \advance\multirow@dima \multirow@cntb\bigstrutjot
  \if*#4\multirow@vbox{#1}{}{\hbox{\strut#6\strut}}%
  \else \if=#4\multirow@setcolwidth{#6}%
    \multirow@vbox{#1}{\hsize\multirow@colwidth\@parboxrestore}{\strut#6\strut\par}%
  \else \multirow@vbox{#1}{\hsize#4\@parboxrestore}{\strut#6\strut\par}%
  \fi \fi
  \ifdim#2pt>\z@
    \if#1t\relax\multirow@dima=\ht0\else
      \multirow@dima=\ht\@arstrutbox
      \ifmultirow@prefixt \advance\multirow@dima\bigstrutjot\fi
      \if#1b\relax \advance\multirow@dima\dp\@arstrutbox
        \ifmultirow@prefixb \advance\multirow@dima\bigstrutjot\fi
      \fi
    \fi
  \else
    \if#1b\relax\else
      \advance\multirow@dima-\dp\@arstrutbox
      \ifmultirow@prefixb \advance\multirow@dima-\bigstrutjot\fi
      \if#1t\relax\advance\multirow@dima-\ht\@arstrutbox
        \ifmultirow@prefixt \advance\multirow@dima-\bigstrutjot\fi
        \advance\multirow@dima\ht0
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \advance\multirow@dima#5\relax
  \leavevmode\a:multirow
  \setbox0\vtop{\vskip-\multirow@dima\box0\vss}\dp0=\z@
  \ifmultirowdebug{\showboxdepth=5 \showboxbreadth=10 \showbox0}\fi
  \box0\b:multirow
}
\NewConfigure{multirow}{2}

\Hinput{multirow}
\endinput
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: However, the content of the multirow cell is not vertically centered as it happens in the pdf output. Is this feature not currently available?

Comment: @e_moro yes, this feature is not available, because HTML needs a special structure of the table to support cells that span over several rows and it is not easily possible to achieve it.

Comment: Maybe in the future. Anyway, congratulations to the whole tex4ht's contributors team for their amazing work.

Comment: @e_moro thanks for your kind words. maybe it could be possible to fix merged rows with some Lua post-processing in `make4ht`.